# MKUserLocation is selectable, falsely intercepting touches from custom MKAnnotationViews

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapkit, mkannotationview, mkuserlocation

I have a normal map in my iOS app where "Shows Users Location" is enabled - meaning I have my normal blue dot on the map, showing my position and accuracy info. The callout is disabled in code.

But I also have custom MKAnnotationViews that are plotted around the map which all have custom callouts.

This is working fine, but the problem is that when my location is on the location of a MKAnnotationView, the blue dot (MKUserLocation) intercepts the touch, so the MKAnnotationView doesn't get touched.

How can I disable the user interaction on the blue dot so that the touches are intercepted by the MKAnnotationViews and not the blue dot?

This is what I do so far:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)map viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation;
{
    if (annotation == self.mapView.userLocation)
    {
        [self.mapView viewForAnnotation:annotation].canShowCallout = NO;
        return [self.mapView viewForAnnotation:annotation];
    } else {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 17):

Disabling the callout doesn't disable touches on the view (`didSelectAnnotationView` will still get called).

To disable user interaction on an annotation view, set its `enabled` property to `NO`.

However, instead of setting `enabled` to `NO` in the `viewForAnnotation` delegate method, I suggest doing it in the `didAddAnnotationViews` delegate method instead and in `viewForAnnotation`, just return `nil` for `MKUserLocation`.

Example:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)map viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation;
{
    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]])
    {
        return nil;
    }

    //create annotation view for your annotation here...
}

-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didAddAnnotationViews:(NSArray *)views
{
    MKAnnotationView *av = [mapView viewForAnnotation:mapView.userLocation];
    av.enabled = NO;  //disable touch on user location
}
```

Comment: I'm suggesting setting `enabled` to `NO` in `didAddAnnotationViews` for the user location annotation only.  If you wanted to disable interaction on your own annotations, you can do that in `viewForAnnotation` when creating your view.

Comment: Excellent suggestion using enabled instead of userInteractionEnabled. Solved my problem with stacked annotations!

Answer (score 0):

Swift 4.2 Example:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation)   ->     MKAnnotationView? {
    if annotation is MKUserLocation {
        return nil
    }
// Add custom annotation views here.
}

func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didAdd views: [MKAnnotationView])      {
    // Grab the user location annotation from your IB Outlet map view.
    let userLocation = mapView.view(for: mapView.userLocation)
    userLocation?.isEnabled = false
}
```